# cakephp 3.0 same controller name for admin and users

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp 3.0 and want to write some admin actions and some users actions in users controller. admin actions should be accessible from admin routing and user actions should be accessible without admin routing

I know in cakephp 3.0 for admin, users controller should be in

src/Controller/Admin/UsersController.php

and for normal users, users controller should be in

src/Controller/UsersController.php

Now the confusion is,
Is this correct to put same controller name is in 2 different directories or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Your access point is difference like /src/Controller/Admin/ControllerName and /src/Controller/ControllerName You can use both ControllerName and ActionName remaining same.

Suppose you want to make a UsersController in both admin and public section. you also want to make an actionName in the controller. It would be like:

```
//Name it in Admin Directory  /src/Controller/Admin/UsersController.php
public function index()
{
    $this->layout = 'admin_default';
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate($this->Users));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
}

//Name it in Public Directory  /src/Controller/UsersController.php
public function index()
{
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate($this->Users));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
}
```

Hope it will make you understand.

Comment: If it helps you, please make this answer is correct.. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it good idea to have same controller names in 2 different paths?

Comment: If you bake for admin prefix, It makes controllers same as public for us and it is also keep us to remember with same name but if needed you can change it as you want to.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep them in the same UsersController by defining routes in routes.php file something like this:

```
// Connect routes for admin prefix.
Router::connect(
    'admin/users',
    ['plugin' => false, 'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'adminIndex']
);
Router::connect(
    'admin/users/:action/*',
    ['plugin' => false, 'controller' => 'Users']
);
```

If you notice in the code above, I have specified `adminIndex` action for admin index action. By doing so you could create a different set of actions and views to keep them more manageable while keeping them at one place.

For larger application however it is good idea to keep admin area separated from the front end area. It's your choice after all.